# Compare Two Arrays and Remove Unique Values

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance

I have two arrays

```
ordered = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

some_list = [2, 6, 4]
```

I would like to compare the two arrays, then find the duplicates, and form it into a new array. The trick is to keep the array in the order provided in the `ordered` array.

```
new_array = [2, 4] # Result should be this
```

I've thought of one way to do it, however I think the performance can be improved.

```
ordered.each do |value1|
  some_list.include? value1 
    new_array << value1
  end
end
```

Is there any way I can improve this?

Benchmark results

```
                   user     system      total        real
  using &        0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.212070)
  using select   0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.218889)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this `new_arry = order­ed & some_­list`

Comment: That's nicely terse syntax, but is it hoisted into optimized code compared to his loop, or will it end up being equivalent speed but still nicer to type?

Comment: I'm running benchmarks to compare the two as I speak...

Comment: this answer will not maintain order. I updated it to `new_arry = order­ed & some_­list` so it keeps the ordered that is defined in `ordered` array? order of elements in new array depend on the first array.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni You gotta read the ruby doc for your answer http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26 . Its an inbuilt function and i bet i would be far more optimized than the number of loops jason is running

Comment: @luri G Thanks for refactoring me :)

Comment: @jason328 it would be great if you can share the benchmarks with us. Would be a learning experience for us as well :)

Comment: Doing that as we speak.

Comment: @Raghu I would guess that as well but it's not clear from the ruby documentation which would be better since an int hashes and equality are both operations that can be done at a very low level, but since ruby is generally an interpreted language....

Comment: Aghh, you're ahead by 0.006819 secs! ;-)

Comment: hopefully there's a reason ruby is being used to write something where this optimization is significant ;)

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done in following way:

```
uniques = ordered - some_list
duplicates = ordered - uniques
```

Order will be preserved.

Refer: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2D

Answer (score 1):

```
ordered.select{|i| some_list.include?(i)}
```

Edit:

Not really sure if select is optimised for performance, but it is provided as shorter and clear alternative to the code provided by the OP.

A quick benchmark gave this results:
Edit: adding the accepted answer alternative.

```
           user     system      total        real
  each  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000005)
select  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000004)
     &  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000005)
```

Comment: isn't this just shorthand for his second loop? Is select significantly optimized by comparison? (not a ruby guy)

Comment: Yeah I actually just realized there is marginal results. Hmm. I'm going to give him credit since he answered first before you. I like you used select though, I didn't think about it.

Comment: I ran benchmark and if you compare big arrays of strings with reversed order (so its harder to match for CPU) then you get order of magnitudes difference in speed. `&` was 30 times faster than `select` with `include`.